# How can I launch an application page when alarm give notification in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am making an application in which I have to launch an game page when the alarm shoots on windows phone 
actually you saw someone reply in a post n m really like to know
how is it possible?

Comment: I think you need to clarify a bit better what you need help with. Launch a game page? Are you already inside the game? What kind of alarm? The more info, the better answers you'll probably get.

Comment: actually there is an feature in my app which is "i m a hardsleeper "
when the user cheak on that open then whenever the alarm runs it should open a simple game that a user have to compelete so that app can verify that he/shez awake 
so i need help to launch that page whenver the alarm provokes n user tap on ok button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting up a reminder. Use the following code to do this -

```
//Create a reminder
Reminder myReminder = new Reminder("buy milk");
myReminder.Title = "Buy Milk";
myReminder.Content = "Don't forget to buy milk!";
myReminder.BeginTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
myReminder.ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(15);
myReminder.RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.None;
myReminder.NavigationUri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?fromReminder=1",         UriKind.Relative);

//Add the reminder to the ScheduledActionService
ScheduledActionService.Add(myReminder);
```

The NavigationUri property is used to specify the page to which you want to launch the application to. Here are a couple of links for more information

[Tutorial](http://blog.markarteaga.com/WindowsPhoneMultitaskingndashScheduledNotifications.aspx)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.reminder%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: how is this possible to create an alarm with in the app 
can u give me a link or an example ? m new with this notification stuff

Comment: I have corrected my answer. You can accept it as the right answer if you feel it helps you. :)